# How to minimize other accordions if one accordion clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I am using jQuery accordion, Accordion is working perfect on one page, but not working on another page.

for eg; in http://mobiletest.me/ipad_mini_emulator/?u=http://www.hadeyaa.com/checkout if I click on login $ than Express Checkout. Than only one should open at a time. But 2 accordions are getting opened.

where as its working perfect on http://mobiletest.me/ipad_mini_emulator/?u=http://www.hadeyaa.com/login.

I am using following html for accordion.

```
<div class="row visible-xs visible-sm">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" >Registered Customers</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          accordion 1
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" >New Customers</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
           <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                accordion 2 
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first loop all accordion items and remove the open class if it has one. After that you then append the class to the one you want open.

Remove class "in" and then set attribute aria-expanded to false so bootstrap knows what to do when the user clicks it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have 2 div with same "accordion" id, remove the outer one and the accordion will work.